# Inputs equality check using jQuery without plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I tried creating a function to check for a match between two email fields, let's say EMAIL and CONFIRM email. I absolutely try to avoid jQuery validate. It is not worth it for a single field. For the rest I use HTML5 properties like required, pattern, etc. and it works well. This is why I want to deliver seamless experience with setCustomValidity.

Here's my working code, which of course, may be improved by someone with more experience in JS and jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<input type="email" name="addr1" id="addr1" required>
<input type="email" name="addr2" data-equal-to="addr1" data-msg-error="Emails do not match." required>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[data-equal-to]').on('blur', function() {
    var to_confirm = $(this),
        to_equal = $('#' + to_confirm.data('equal-to'));
    if (to_confirm.val() != to_equal.val()) {
        this.setCustomValidity(to_confirm.data('msg-error'));
    }
    else {
        this.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    to_equal.one('blur', function() {
        to_confirm.trigger('blur');
    });
});
```

Here are the problems I encountered:

1. I was using '.bind'. It turns out its deprecated. Then I started using
   '.on'
2. I forgot the last 3 lines. There was no event listener for the
   first email input, so I was only checking the CONFIRM input. This
   got fixed.
3. I was using 'input' instead of 'blur'. 'input' provided
   real-time validation (as you type) which is good, but consumed too
   much in my opinion. Also it showed errors while you are still typing
   (and haven't finished), so some users may find it confusing. The only
   drawback of 'blur' I find is that feedback on validity comes after
   you click another element (unfocus).
4. Binding on every input a new listener to 'to_equal' turned out to be a bad idea. I ended up with multiple listeners, causing the browser to crash. I found out that '.one' exists, which should do the same as .off before .on (or maybe after?)

My question is - can this little script be improved in terms of speed, or using less event listeners? Is there a case I haven't thought of? I searched a lot to find a good no plugin solution, but with no luck. Also I insist on using data- attributes to provide the matching id + the error message (as the website is multi-lingual and its easier to modify HTML than JS on the fly).

I think that having the 'perfect' version of this script will help a lot of people, especially in confirm email/password (for passwords case sensitivity must be in mind!) aspect.

Comment: why not just use a javascript `==` or `===`?

Comment: You provide us with working code which you want to improve. I think this question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Comment: Dear Wouter Bouwman, you're probably right. I wasn't aware of CODE REVIEW, as the SA community saw a major grow since my last presence. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

try onFocusOut event. User typing validating e-mail not check. If leave this input whith tab or clic triggered check function.
For example:
jsfiddle.net/Qh0stM4N/cf757e82/1/
we were able to control it at every keystroke. But it will be taken when the user finishes writing the best result in terms of the user and goes to another form element. If this is not a problem to check when a button is pressed whenever there is a change, and you want to verify HTML5, you can do it using this tool 
codepen.io/diegoleme/pen/surIK

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply giving the second input an id of addr2, and then saying

`if($("#addr1").val() != $("#addr2").val())`

?

Comment: this makes no sense, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Reusable code with classes and siblings:

```
$('.mail')              .on('keyup', checkPasses)
function checkPasses (e) {
    $ps1 = $(e.delegateTarget)
    $ps2 = $ps1.siblings('.psw')
    $pss = $ps1.add($ps2)
    if ( $ps1.val() == $ps2.val() ) {
        $pss.css('color', 'green')[0].setCustomValidity('')         
  } else {      
        $pss.css('color', 'red')[0].setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match')
    }
}
```